# Creating tables in a radom in python

Tags: python-3.x

My aim is to create a table using two list. I was successful creating this, but I need this result in random order, not in sequence. Here my question how my result to make random from my output.

Is there any other method?

```
a = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = [12,13,14,15,16,17,19]
for i in b:
    for j in a:
        print(i,'x',j,'=,')
```

Comment: Hi, I've formatted your code. Please double check; you had no indentation at all, and I'm just guessing you have nested loops. [Edit] as necessary. You may also want to add the actual and expected output, to make clear what you are asking. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the desired result:

```
from random import randint

a = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = [12,13,14,15,16,17,19]

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(0, len(b)):
        aNum = a[randint(0, len(a)-1)]
        bNum = b[randint(0, len(b)-1)]
        print(aNum, 'x', bNum, '=')
        a.remove(aNum)
        b.remove(bNum)
```

Comment: can you explain code how it works (aNum = a[randint(0, len(a)-1)]) and what is purpose of write code a.remove(aNum)         b.remove(bNum) at end.

Comment: Sure, the aNum and bNum variables each give a random number from each of the lists, it is does this by generating a random number between 0 and the length of the list -1 it then gets the number at the index of the random number given. For example in the 1st iteration the list is 8 elements therefore a random number between 0 and 7 will be generated lets say the random number is 3 it will then take the 4th element from that list which in this case is five and store that number in the variable aNum. The a.remove() is simply there to remove the numbers that have been used so they arent reused

Comment: thank you Jack, I am really happy with your explination. one more doubt please calrify. a[randint(0,len(a))] while running this code am getting error. 'IndexError: list index out of range' I didn't understand why index out of range, we are giving with len(a)

Comment: You would need to do a[randint(0, len(a)-1)] as list indexing starts at 0 rather than 1 so if you do a[randint(0, len(a))] you will be generating random numbers from 0 to 8 rather than 0 to 7. This will give a list index out of range error as the list only goes to index 7. The following link gives some good insite into manipulating and using lists in python: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp

Comment: Thank you giving explanation, where I learn I didn't get like this, you explained to me.